# Gull engine : Which depth value to set 6 difficulty levels?

Tags: software, programming

We are installing the Gull engine for some chess enthusiasts in an organization.
We would like to set 6 difficulty levels from beginner to master using depth.
Is there someone who can advice us about which values are the most accurate and progressive for each level?

Comment: Can you just do 3,4,5,6,7,8 etc?

Comment: depth is the number of half moves the search nominally looks ahead, so it's a little bit hard to define. Middle game junior usually gets 14-16 depth to be competitive

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this post](https://lichess.org/blog/U4mtoEQAAEEAgZRL/strongest-chess-player-ever) by the developers of the website https://lichess.org/ helpful.

Although they use [Stockfish](http://stockfishchess.org/) as the engine, they set the search depths as such (note that they have eight levels of play):

- AI level 1: skill 3/20, depth 1, 50ms
- AI level 2: skill 6/20, depth 2, 100ms
- AI level 3: skill 9/20, depth 3, 150ms
- AI level 4: skill 11/20, depth 4, 200ms
- AI level 5: skill 14/20, depth 6, 250ms
- AI level 6: skill 17/20, depth 8, 300ms
- AI level 7: skill 20/20, depth 10, 350ms
- AI level 8: skill 20/20, depth 12, 400ms

I have personally played and seen others play against the varying levels. Level 1 is almost joke worthy--the computer may move his queen completely into danger, completely miss checkmates, etc.

On the other hand, level eight is crushing; beating it requires repeated practice over the same line (at least, that is the only way I've seen people beat it).